# how to display only billing_id from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [billing_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [billing_id] => 2
                )
         )
)
```

how to display only billing_id from this array?

Comment: have you asign any name to this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach in billing_id array container :

```
  $my_array = array(0=>array(array('billing_id'=>86),array('billing_id'=>1)));

            $i=0;
            foreach($my_array as $billingid){
                echo $billingid[$i]['billing_id'];
            $i++;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ex. $data[1]['billing_id']; try like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array_name[1]['biling_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how u make it like this but if you need only data : `first[0][0]['billing_id']`

Comment: first[0][0]['billing_id']

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$result = array_map(function ($element) {
    return $element['billing_id'];
}, $arrayName[0]);

echo implode(', ', $result);
```

shorten code (without commas in result):

```
array_map(function ($elem) {
    echo $elem['billing_id'];
}, $arrayName[0]);
```

Comment: @ankur43 array_map first param is callback. array_map will call function each time, you have an elements in $arrayName[0], and put this element to function. Actually you can name it by yourselfe.

Comment: @ankur43 you can change return to echo. and delete last line. it can be shorten code)))

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($x as $m)
        {
            for($j=0 ; $j<25;$j++){
            echo ($m[$i]['billing_id'].",");
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

where $x is the nameof the array